# Functions in batch programming for loop

Tags: batch-file

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1,2,3 delims=," %%a in (%1) do (
echo %%a %%b %%c
call :periodic_file_deletion %%a %%b %%c
)

:periodic_file_deletion
set deletion_path=%1
set search_mask=%2
set timegap=%3
echo %deletion_path% %search_mask% %timegap%
```

%1 is the input file param.txt which contains

> C:\script\periodic_file_deletion\log,*.log,2
>   C:\script,*.srf,2

My output is

> C:\script\periodic_file_deletion\log *.log 2
>   C:\script\periodic_file_deletion\log *.log 2
>   C:\script *.srf 2
>   C:\script *.srf 2
>   C:\script\test\param.txt

I understood the first 4 lines..the last line comes as it takes the echo %deletion_path% %search_mask% %timegap% with a %1 as param.txt. I don't understand why.

I want a particular function code block to run only when it is called for. How can I do that? How can I remove the last line from output?

Answer (score 0):

Unlike many languages, batch has no concept of the end of a "procedure" - it simply continues execution line-by-line until it reaches the end-of-file. Consequently, you need to `goto :eof` after completing the mainline, otherwise execution will continue through the subroutine code. `:EOF` is a predefined label understood by `CMD` to mean `end of file`. The colon is **required**.

Your code is currently "flowing through" to the procedure after finishing the main code.

Comment: Thanks.. But how can I get my desired output here?

Comment: By inserting a line `goto :eof` before the `:periodic_file_deletion` label. It's my practice to mechanically add `goto :eof` at the end of every procedure - even the very last procedure in a batch, where it is redundant. In this manner, flow-through to any additional procedures that may be added can be avoided.

Comment: In addition..

Does for loop read a text file line by line?
What is the difference between goto :eof and exit?

Comment: yes - skips empty lines and those that begin `;`. There's very little difference in effect, but if you `exit` a batch then it terminates the `cmd` instance, which is very inconvenient for iterative debugging.

Comment: You can use `exit /b` to terminate the script without closing the cmd terminal (unless you ran the script by double-clicking it).